# OpenVPN and port translation

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

So, here's the deal. I have an openvpn instance on a port 443.
I need it to also be on port 993, the same instance, the same virtual network.
Openvpn can not really do that, but Linux comes with iptables, so we slap a rule that translates one port to another:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dst x.x.x.23 --dport 993 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443
```

It just takes packets from one port ant throws them into another on some IP. tried it on SSH, and it works. So, problem solved, right?

Wrong. When I fire up an OpenVPN config with port changed to 993, I get the following:

```
WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (15464), which must be > 0 and <= 1560 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attempting restart...]
```

So, okay. I increase --link-mtu on client, and it still does not connect, now without any explainantion.
What is wrong? And how do I fix it?

Comment: I can confirm that `iptables` `port` `redirct` works ok for `OpenVPN` using `--proto tcp`. Perhaps there is something wrong with your OpenVPN configuration files. Or maybe there is _a possible active attack on the TCP link_

Comment: Why do you increase the `MTU` ? `MTU` has nothing to do with `port redirect`